# Killing command in subshell

Tags: macos, bash, process, tail, rundeck

I want to tail a file and output its content until a certain pattern is reached. Currently, I am doing this:

```
grep -q 'pattern' <(tail -F /my/file | tee /dev/stderr)
exit 0
```

This works fine, but the problem here is that even when this bash process exits, there will be a process for tail hanging around. This is a problem for Rundeck, since it will think that my command hasn't finished yet. I have tried these options:

1. Use tail --pid=$$. This works in Linux, but I am working on Mac, whose tail version doesn't support --pid.
2. Use "kill 0". This will indeed kill the tail process, but it will also crash Rundeck (sic).

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You should be [grouping commands](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Grouping.html) instead:

```
{ tail -F /my/file | tee /dev/stderr; } | grep -q 'pattern'
```

Now `grep` would send a `SIGPIPE` to the previous command in the pipeline when it finds the *pattern*.

Comment: I tried that, but now my bash process doesn't exit at all (even though "pattern" appears in the output).

Comment: @user1013725 It's odd.  I wrote that after testing!

Comment: Ah, I think it's because "pattern" is the last string in the file. If something comes after, it seems to finish.